# Enemy patrolling in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine

So im creating a 2D game in Unity and i want an enemy to just patrol in this one area until it finds the player. I found a youtube tutorial about this but my enemy just runs to one direction until it falls of the map.

heres the code i followed from the video

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyPatrol : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject pointA;
    public GameObject pointB;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Animator anim;
    private Transform currentPoint;
    public float speed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        currentPoint = pointB.transform;
        anim.SetBool("IsRunning", true);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 point = currentPoint.position = transform.position;
        if(currentPoint == pointB.transform)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
        }

        if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, currentPoint.position) < 50f && currentPoint == pointB.transform)
        {
            currentPoint = pointA.transform;
        }

        if(Vector2.Distance(transform.position, currentPoint.position) < 50f && currentPoint == pointA.transform)
        {
            currentPoint = pointB.transform;
        }
    }
}
```

I want the enemy to patrol between 2 points and then detect the player and attack.

Comment: firstly it is incredibly rare that a transform will exactly equal another.  Which is why your vector speeds never flip.. As you have better code below it deciding if it got there or not,  although 50f seems a long way, why would you not flip the speed there too?

Comment: @bugFinder, is correct (in fact it's a reference comparison so it will never be equal ;). you'll have to compare the position values against some threshold value

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to check the enemy position and make sure the z position is 0.